# LED Strip Wiring S Connection

Tags: wiring, led-strip

Can anyone explain the best way to wire up 6 LED strips of 60 pixels in S type connection?

I'd like all of the data direction to be up, instead of up-down

[image: Example]

Comment: Are you saying you want the data flow from the top of a given column of pixels to come to the _bottom_ of the next column instead of just connecting to the nearby top pixel? What is the reason for that? (If it's for programming reasons, you should consider making a translation or look-up-table so you abstract the wiring sequence away from firmware development.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flip the ‘down’ strings so that their data direction is the same, and make a hidden connection end to end with a passive jumper between rows (so, wired like a ‘Z’ instead of an ‘S’.)

Or, remap the LEDs by software.